# How to create an epicurve (Histogram) using date and time variables?

Tags: r, date, datetime, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to create an epicurve for a foodborne illness that happened over the course of several days. Basically, it is a histogram where the y axis is the number of sick individuals, and the x axis is chronological time (at the level of hours). I used characters from Finding Nemo and a fake data set to avoid using real data which obviously would not be appropriate.

This is the dataset:

```
# A tibble: 11 × 3
   first_name last_name     symptom_onset      
   <chr>      <chr>         <dttm>             
 1 Nemo       Clownfish     2023-05-20 01:23:11
 2 Marlin     Clownfish     2023-05-19 16:03:22
 3 Dory       Tang          NA                 
 4 Bruce      Shark         2023-05-19 16:55:33
 5 Nigel      Pelican       2023-05-19 18:22:24
 6 Peach      Starfish      2023-05-20 01:03:18
 7 Tad        Butterflyfish 2023-05-21 02:10:16
 8 Crush      Turtle        2023-05-20 01:40:37
 9 Squirt     Turtle        2023-05-20 01:45:23
10 Pearl      Octopus       2023-05-20 01:32:26
11 Jacques    Shrimp        2023-05-20 02:54:08
```

The variables `first_name`, `last_name`, and `symptom_onset` represent the name of the individual and the date and time they developed symptoms. By using the as.date() function, I can easily create an epicurve using this code:

```
finding_nemo$symptom_onset <- as.Date(finding_nemo$symptom_onset)

ggplot(data=finding_nemo, aes(x=symptom_onset))+
  geom_histogram(fill="#197C67")+
  geom_text(stat="count", aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1)+
  labs(title="EpiCurve for Sick Fish at Nemo's Picnic", x="Symptom Onset", y="Number of Cases")+
  scale_x_date(limits=as.Date(c("2023-05-15", "2023-05-25")))+ #This line of code specifies the date range that we want to see in the epicurve
  theme_minimal()
```

The resulting chart looks like this:

[image]

However, the as.date() function chops off the time stamp and so the epicurve (histogram) only represents dates and I would like to have the granularity of time.

So, what I would like to do is be able to make this chart with the x axis showing date and time, and the bars representing illness counts every 2 hours over the specific period of time. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: does using `scale_x_datetime(breaks = "2 hours")` rather than `scale_x_date` help? (And don't use `as.Date()` on your `onset` variable, leave it as a date-time ...

Comment: To add to to Ben's excellent advice, you may want to try using `finding_nemo$symptom_onset <- as.POSIXct(finding_nemo$symptom_onset, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` instead of `as.Date()` - or `lubridate::ymd_hms(finding_nemo$symptom_onset)`